# show html option value codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, html-select

I'm new in Codeignite. I have a "Test" Controller with "index()" and "view($id)" functions. the index method goes to "test1.php" view. In "test1.php", I have a dropdown options. if I submit on this page, the "view" method of "Test" Controller will be called. My question is how can I pass the option value to "view" function , so that the argument of method will be set to  the option value and then the url would be something like `"http://localhost/test/view/id"` which the id is option value from "test1.php"

Test Controller

```
class Test extends CI_Controller{
   public function indx() {
     //some code
      $this->load->view('test1.php');
   }
   public function view($id)
   {
     //some code, here I  use $id which I want to be option value from test1.php
   }
```

test1.php

```
<?php 
$options = array(
              '1'  => 'One',
              '2'    => 'Two',
              '3' => 'Three',
              '4' => 'Four',
            );

$js = 'id="shirts" onChange="this.form.submit();"';
echo form_dropdown('shirts', $options, '1', $js);
/* here I want to call echo form_open() as echo form_open("/test/view/[option  value]") but I don't know how to do this;*/
```

Answer (score 0):

You can load view with data.

```
class Test extends CI_Controller{
   public function index($id) {
      $this->data['result'] = get_results($id);
      $this->load->view('test1.php', $this->data);
   }
}
```

In the view file:

```
foreach ($results as $result) {
   // action
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If its essential that you pass the ID in the URL then you'll need to use javascript to append the ID to the form action URL using a **change** event listener on the select field.

However, IMHO, you would be better off just retrieving the value within the **view()** method from the POST data.

Using **$id = $this->input->post('shirts', TRUE)**, rather than forcing it through the URL.